# How to write inline query in HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

How do I write this query in HQL?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN data1 > data2 THEN data1 ELSE data2 END AS data, STAMP FROM 
(SELECT STAMP, max(mc.data1) as data1, max(mc.data2) as data2 FROM 
transaction_history mc LEFT JOIN orderdetails gc on mc.id = gc.id where 
gc.order_name in ('xxx','yyy') AND time >= 135689 AND time <= 137692) AS TBL
```

When I tried to replicate the above query in HQL I got:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException exception saying unexpected token "(".
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use detached criteria and join it with main criteria using corelated subquery and then use formulas on fields in the entity to achieve this. Hibernate does not have inline query support like you have done.